# PG::Error timezone when changing string column to time data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, postgresql, rails-migrations

I need to change column data type, currently these columns are strings, but I need to change that it would be "time".

**Migration file:**

```
def change
  change_column :enquiries, :start_time, :time
  change_column :enquiries, :end_time, :time
end
```

**Error message:**

> PG::Error: ERROR:  column "start_time" cannot be cast automatically to
>   type time without time zone HINT:  You might need to specify "USING
>   start_time::time without time zone".

After some searches I found this solution, but it still not working, however I get new error message.

```
def change
  change_column :enquiries, :start_time, 'time USING CAST(start_time AS time)'
  change_column :enquiries, :end_time, 'time USING CAST(end_time AS time)'
end
```

> PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: ""

I tried **matthewd** solution but it still not works.

```
change_column :enquiries, :start_time, "time USING CAST(NULLIF(start_time, '') AS time)"
```

> PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "09.00"

Any help how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is what I did. There was a lot of start_time and end_time records and these two columns didn't have validation so some records were not correct formation (HH:MM).
However, need to refactor this code, but this is what worked for me.

```
def up
  rename_column :enquiries, :start_time, :start_time_old
  rename_column :enquiries, :end_time, :end_time_old
  add_column :enquiries, :start_time, :time
  add_column :enquiries, :end_time, :time

  Enquiry.reset_column_information
  Enquiry.find_each do |e| 
    unless e.start_time_old.blank?
      if e.start_time_old.include?('.')
        e.update_column(:start_time , e.start_time_old.gsub('.', ':'))
      else
        e.update_column(:start_time , e.start_time_old)
      end
    end
  end

  Enquiry.find_each do |e| 
    unless e.end_time_old.blank?
      if e.end_time_old.include?('.')
        e.update_column(:end_time , e.end_time_old.gsub('.', ':'))
      else
        e.update_column(:end_time , e.end_time_old)
      end
    end
  end

  remove_column :enquiries, :start_time_old
  remove_column :enquiries, :end_time_old
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The second error is caused by existing rows that have a blank string as their value in one of your `*_time` columns: as it says, that's not valid input for the `time` type.

The most plausible choice would be to convert those to NULL, which you can do using the `NULLIF` SQL function:

```
change_column :enquiries, :start_time, "time USING CAST(NULLIF(start_time, '') AS time)"
```

Comment: Or separate `up`/`down` methods with `execute('update ...')` before the column change if there's more garbage in the `start_time` and `end_time` columns. You could mash more into the cast expression but it can get ugly depending on the nature of the garbage.

Comment: User can also do: `change_column :enquiries, :start_time, :time, using: "CAST(NULLIF(start_time, '') AS time)"` to keep the column type as an arg.